# How to get the uploaded file with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, symfony

I am building up a profile setter form using Symfony3 and I'm stuck with the avatar.

The avatar field is a standard Symfony3 File form field which work fine.

Here is some code.

In the Entity file (`Profile.php`) :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true) 
 * @Assert\File(
 *      mimeTypes={"image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/bmp", "image/tiff"},
 * )
 */
private $avatar;
```

In the twig template (`profile_edit.html.twig`)

```
{{ form_row(form.avatar) }}
```

When the user upload a image file, I would like the image to appear on a div and the use [Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=thumbnail) onto it. Then, the cropped image should be sent to the form.

**How to get the uploaded file using jQuery for edits ?

How to set the Symfony uploaded file form using jQuery ?**

PS : For some reasons, it is very hard for me to include any other Bundle in my Symfony config for now.